# Perl regular expression to match everything between double quotes?

Tags: regex, perl, double-quotes

The text is:

```
some text here x"/get/me/out/of/here.png"
```

How can I get everything between the double quotes?

This seems not to work:

```
if ($text =~ /".+?"/) {
 print"found: $1\n";
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

You need to have a `$1`, so wrap parenthesis around`.+?`:

```
$text = 'foo "bar baz" mu';

if ($text =~ /"(.+?)"/) {
  print"found: $1\n";
}
```

prints:

```
bar baz
```

Or use `$&` to grab the entire match (`"bar baz"`: including the double quotes):

```
if ($text =~ /".+?"/) {
  print"found: $&\n";
}
```

Comment: Should really use `[^"]*` instead of `.`, no? Just in case there are other quotes later on, and `*` in case it's empty.

Comment: @Tom, yeah, I'd also prefer `[^"]+` or `[^"]*` over `.+?` (perhaps the OP is not interested in empty strings?).

Comment: @Tom, but the fact that the `.` is made un-greedy, it wouldn't matter if there are other quotes later on. Nonetheless, `[^"]` is IMO preferred.

Comment: Ah, the `?`. Don't remember the fine points of Perl regexes, I haven't used it lately. But yes, I agree, the `[^"]` seems more robust and straightforward to me.

Comment: +1 - and if you want to allow escaped chars (including escaped quotes) use: `/"[^"\\]*(\\.[^"\\]*)*"/`

Comment: @ridherunner, that's when its better to go for a module, something like [`Text::Balanced`](http://p3rl.org/Text::Balanced)

Comment: @BartKiers Do I have to escape double quotes, like this? `=~ /\".+?"/` instead of just `=~ /".+?"/`?

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev, no, `/".+?"/` is the correct form. If that does not result in a match, the quotes might be on different lines (by default, the `.` char does not match line break chars!). In that case, add the `s` (DOT-ALL) modifier:  `/".+?"/s`

Answer (score 5):

As always, any time you think that a Regex is the best solution (and occasionally it might be), a quick trip to CPAN may find you something better. In this case [`Text::Balanced`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::Balanced). There is the `extract_delimited` or `extract_quotelike` function which will extract text between specified quotes.

Read the instructions carefully, as it has useful but perhaps unexpected behaviors. However it can be very useful, especially if you have to do repeated extractions.